# Android scrollTo with animation that starts from scrollposition

Tags: android, animation, scroll, objectanimator

I have an ObjectAnimator that currently scrolls my container to a certain view. The problem I have with this Animation is that it doesn't seem to take the start position in account. Instead of starting the scrolling animation from the current position, it jumps to top and then scrolls down. How to let the scroll animation start from the current position?

This is my current working code:

```
objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mainView, "scrollY", 0, scrollToView.getTop()).setDuration(500);
                objectAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops that was easy

```
objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mainView, "scrollY", mainView.getScrollY(), scrollToView.getTop()).setDuration(500);
```